# copying html files automatically copies the related image folder. how this works?

Tags: javascript, html

i saved a html file from a website with images. The files are

```
 i. abc.html

 ii. abc_files/img1.jpg
```

when i copy and paste the html file only(abc.html),the abc_files(images folder) automatically getting copied.

1. Why this happens?
2. is there a standard that respective images for an html has to be inside an folder and that folder should follow a naming convention as above?

Answer (score 4):

Its a (non-extensible) feature of the shell:

> With Windows 2000 or later, it is possible to connect an HTML file
>   with a folder that contains related files such as Graphics Interchange
>   Format (GIF) images or style sheets. If file connection is enabled,
>   when you move or copy the HTML file, the connected folder and all of
>   its files are also moved or copied. Conversely, if you move the folder
>   with the related files, the HTML file is also move

See [Connecting Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) @ MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

How were you saving the html?  It's possible that you selected an option where you save the whole page, as opposed to just the html file.

As for the image, most likely, the website where you got the html from stored its images in a folder for organization, so in order for the downloaded html to work properly, the images are downloaded in same organizational structure.

I don't think it's necessarily a standard that images have to be stored in a folder like that, but it makes it easier to separate the files, and keep things clean.